# How to populate columns as rows in Netezza

Tags: sql, transpose, netezza

I am new to Netezza and I need your help in converting 15 columns to rows in the target table.

I have come across REGEXP functions but I am not sure of exact syntax.

Here is the example :

Source has it as

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5   Col 6
1        2       3        4        5    6
```

Expected target

```
Col A

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have referenced 6 columns here but I have 3 sets of 15 columns so I didnt feel union is a right option.Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

A simple method is `union all`:

```
select col1 as colA from t union all
select col2 from t union all
select col3 from t union all
select col4 from t union all
select col5 from t union all
select col6 from t;
```

I don't see what regexp functions have to do with your question, which is basically how to do "unpivot" in Netezza.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gordon , So there is no other option than union all?

Comment: @Anusha . . . There are, in fact, other options, but `union all` seems sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do 14 UNION ALL you can utilize a CROSS JOIN to a table/query which returns 15 rows with numbers between 1 and 15 (or something similar):

```
select 
   case i
      when 1 then col1
      when 2 then col2
      when 3 then col3
      ...
   end 
from tab 
cross join
 (
   select i from numbers_table where i between 1 and 15
 ) dt
```

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, Can you explain the 'i' here  and crossjoin with dt table?

Comment: As I said, this is just a Select which returns exactly 15 rows with unique values, due to the Cross Join you get each row in the source table 15 times and the `CASE` is used to match each col1 to col15 to a single row

Answer (score 0):

**Cross Join Approach**
Adding to what dnoeth said, you will first want to make sure you have a numbers_table. This will be the table you will cross join to.  In this case, i is not part of a function.  It is just a column name.  It could just as easily be named ColX.  In your example, you have 6 columns, so I am inserting 6 rows, 1-6.  It might be handy to keep a larger version of this table around though.

```
CREATE TABLE NUMBERS_TABLE
(i INT);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO NUMBERS_TABLE VALUES (6);
```

Note: A Cross Join will create a Cartesian Product, so be careful.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6 FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE)

SELECT
,CASE B.i
     WHEN 1 THEN 'COL1'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'COL2'
     WHEN 3 THEN 'COL3'
     WHEN 4 THEN 'COL4'
     WHEN 5 THEN 'COL5'
     WHEN 6 THEN 'COL6'
     END AS UNPIVOTED_COLUMN_NAMES
,CASE B.i
     WHEN 1 THEN A.COL1
     WHEN 2 THEN A.COL2
     WHEN 3 THEN A.COL3
     WHEN 4 THEN A.COL4
     WHEN 5 THEN A.COL5
     WHEN 6 THEN A.COL6
     END AS COLUMN_A
FROM CTE A CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT i FROM NUMBERS_TABLE WHERE i in ('1','2','3','4','5','6')) B
```